# No images are loading in Google Chrome - works fine in Firefox/IE

Tags: image, google-chrome, nivo-slider

For some reason when I use Chrome to test out my website, no images load at all, not even tiny ones like loading icons or the simple "back to top of page" arrow icon at the bottom. The browser tab just hangs on the spinning circle loading state. If I refresh it like 10 times or something then a portion of the images might load. Interestingly my Nivo-Slider images **never load**... there is a large empty space at where the Nivo-Slider gallery should be at the top left of my page no matter how many times I refresh.

The console is completely clean of errors if you check.

Can anyone check for me why my website is not working in Chrome? It works perfectly in Firefox/IE. I admit some images might have large file sizes but it shouldn't cause Chrome to hang for like half an hour?

I'm using latest Chrome/IE/Firefox. Windows 7 64-bit.

My website: www.symphonyofpromise.com/inspiration/en

By the way my website is a completely fictional museum/gallery project, it's not the official site for some museum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot be 100% certain on this, but judging from the Network panel, you might be loading too many MP3 files at the same time, thus maxing out the number of simultaneous requests.  Chrome might use a different prioritization algorithm.

I would recommend removing some of those MP3 files and deferring loading until after the initial load.

EDIT:
Nevermind that, it appears that the MP3s load fine, but other resources are definitely blocking it.  A request should never be pending this long.  Poke around further in the Network panel and you'll find the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it WAS the music. I checked the network tab and everything loaded except the music. I then set the audio elements to have `preload="none"` and problem solved!